# BAT file to process a list of files

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to create a BAT file to process a list of files (including their full paths). Let's say that I have a text file named filelist.txt with the following content:

```
C:\Temp\a.mp4
C:\Temp\b.mp4
D:\z.mp4
E:\Backup\s.mp4
```

Using a BAT file how do I read filelist.txt and then call an external program to process them one by one?

```
process.exe "C:\Temp\a.mp4" <parameters> "C:\Temp\a.m4a"
process.exe "C:\Temp\b.mp4" <parameters> "C:\Temp\b.m4a"
process.exe "D:\z.mp4" <parameters> "D:\z.m4a"
process.exe "E:\Backup\s.mp4" <parameters> "E:\Backup\s.m4a"
```

The parameters are the same for every file. For the second part I guess there should be a FOR command to remove redundancy. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `for` loop with the `/f` option can be used to read and process a text file line by line.

The `delims=` is to handle any spaces that may be in the paths, and the first `""` is because `start` considers the first set of quotes it finds to be the window title.

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in (filelist.txt) do start "" process.exe "%%A" <parameters> "%%A"
```

Comment: Thanks, this must be it.

Answer (score 0):

`for` can read and parse (to a limited degree) the content of a file.

See its help (`for /?`) for details.

But, the future is PowerShell where this kind of thing is much easier:

```
gc filelistfile.txt | % { command.exe $_ }
```